# How to filter datetime in solr server

Tags: solr, server, filtering

I want to implement datetime range filtering in solr..

**Total dates in my DB is 4 Like below,**
"2020-02-05T**09:33:13.0249513**Z","2020-02-06T10:12:51.0527678Z","2020-02-07T07:00:13.0249513Z", "2020-02-10T10:00:13.0249513Z".

**Query** 
date:[05-02-2020T**11:00:00**Z TO 06-02-2020T11:00:00Z]

**Want answer records**
"2020-02-05T**09:33:13.0249513**Z", "2020-02-06T10:12:51.0527678Z"

Comment: Question need more details...like whats the query.....hows the data been indexed...show us the sample data from solr...

Comment: The date format in your query is different (you have the day first, instead of the regular format?) from the date format used when indexing. You'll need to use the correct format (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.ssss`), and the field should be defined as a proper datetime field: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html#WorkingwithDates-DateFormatting

Comment: when I search records between 2 dates in solr using 
query => date:[07-02-2020 TO 10-02-2020] 
so,It gives proper output but when pass time than it's gives error.
My datetime query is 
date:[07-02-2020T06:00:00.00Z TO 10-02-2020T20:00:00.00Z]
Above query gives output of 07 date not gives 10 date. 
The actual record of 10 date is "10-02-2020T10:00:13.0249513Z" and I serach "10-02-2020T06:00:00.00Z" therefor it not include 10 date result

Comment: Using that date format will not give you the result you're looking for - it'll include anything that starts with `08` as well for example, regardless of dates. You'll have to format your dates and use a proper datetime field type instead of a string field.What you're saying the document contains in the comment is also different from what you have in your question?

Comment: I fire query as per your comment and my field type is DateTime..Query = date:[2020-02-10T09:00:00Z TO 2020-02-11T09:00:00Z]..but it also not work..

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue via Insert Timestamp(1581413679400) in Solr database with actual date (2020-02-11T15:04:39.400Z)and I implementing filtering on Timestamp using [date1TimeStamp TO date2TimeStamp]..It's work nice..

Thank you